# Tensor Flow shuffle_batch() blocks at end of epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tf.train.shuffle_batch() to create batches of input images. It includes a min_after_dequeue parameter that makes sure there's a specified number of elements inside the internal queue, and blocks everything else if there isn't.

```
images, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
  [image, label],
  batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
  num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
  capacity=FLAGS.min_queue_size + 3 * FLAGS.batch_size,
  min_after_dequeue=FLAGS.min_queue_size)
```

At the end of an epoch, when I'm doing evaluation (I'm sure this is also true in training but I haven't tested it), everything blocks. I figured out it's at the same moment the internal shuffle batch queue would be left with less than min_after_dequeue elements. At this time in the program I would ideally like to just dequeue the remaining elements but I'm not sure how.

Apparently this type of blocking inside TF queues can be shut off when you know there's no more elements to enqueue with the .close() method. However, since the underlying queue is hidden inside the function, how do I call that method?

Comment: Could you move the code that worked into an answer and accept it so that it would make it easier for others to see that your question does have an answer without having to read your entire question. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the code that I eventually got to work, although with a bunch of warnings that elements I enqueued were cancelled.

```
lv = tf.constant(label_list)

label_fifo = tf.FIFOQueue(len(filenames),tf.int32,shapes=[[]])
# if eval_data:
    # num_epochs = 1
# else:
    # num_epochs = None
file_fifo = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, shuffle=False, capacity=len(filenames))
label_enqueue = label_fifo.enqueue_many([lv])


reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
result.key, value = reader.read(file_fifo)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value, channels=3)
image.set_shape([128,128,3])
result.uint8image = image
result.label = label_fifo.dequeue()

images, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
  [result.uint8image, result.label],
  batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
  num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
  capacity=FLAGS.min_queue_size + 3 * FLAGS.batch_size,
  min_after_dequeue=FLAGS.min_queue_size)

#in eval file:
label_enqueue, images, labels = load_input.inputs()
#restore from checkpoint in between
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
try:
  threads = []
  for qr in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS):
    threads.extend(qr.create_threads(sess, coord=coord, daemon=True,
                                     start=True))

  num_iter = int(math.ceil(FLAGS.num_examples / FLAGS.batch_size))
  true_count = 0  # Counts the number of correct predictions.
  total_sample_count = num_iter * FLAGS.batch_size

  sess.run(label_enqueue)
  step = 0
  while step < num_iter and not coord.should_stop():
    end_epoch = False
    if step > 0:
        for qr in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS):
            #check if not enough elements in queue
            size = qr._queue.size().eval()
            if size - FLAGS.batch_size < FLAGS.min_queue_size:
                end_epoch = True
    if end_epoch:
        #enqueue more so that we can finish
        sess.run(label_enqueue)
    #actually run step
    predictions = sess.run([top_k_op])
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that running the [`RandomShuffleQueue.close()`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.close) operation will stop the dequeuing threads from blocking when there are fewer than `min_after_dequeue` elements in the queue.

The [`tf.train.shuffle_batch()`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#shuffle_batch) function creates a [`tf.train.QueueRunner`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train.html#QueueRunner) that performs operations on the queue in a background thread. If you start it as follows, passing a [`tf.train.Coordinator`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train.html#Coordinator), you will be able to close the queue cleanly (based on the example [here](http://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html#queuerunner)):

```
sess = tf.Session()
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess, coord=coord)

while not coord.should_stop():
  sess.run(train_op)
# When done, ask the threads to stop.
coord.request_stop()
# And wait for them to actually do it.
coord.join(threads)
```

Comment: That's what I originally thought but it doesn't work. I was forced to explicitly enqueue more elements at the end in order for it to finish an epoch. I think the problem could be that I'm using both a FIFO for labels (integers) and string_input_producer for filenames, then sending an image loaded from the file specified by string_input_producer into shuffle_batch. I'll add the code in the question above

Answer (score 1):

There is  an optional argument allow_smaller_final_batch

"allow_smaller_final_batch: (Optional) Boolean. If True, allow the final batch to be smaller if there are insufficient items left in the queue."