# Training from CSV file - use every train example per epoch

Tags: tensorflow

I have a CSV file with 200.000 training samples that I would like to train my network with.

I'm using an `InputProducer` and `DecodeCSV` to get the data. I then run all the data through `shuffle_batch`, where I set `batch_size=50`, `min_after_dequeue=10000` and `capacity=min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size`.

I then run a loop and call `sess.run()` repeatedly.

The question I have is that I now want to run this for several epochs. In each epoch I would like to exaust the entire training set. I don't think the current setup does this. How would I go about doing that? 
I'm not even sure, if I understood the inner workings of `shuffle_batch` and its parameters fully as of yet.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The queue should block at the end of the epoch. When that happens, you will know that you have exhausted the training set. More information in this related question: [Tensor Flow shuffle_batch() blocks at end of epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34079781/tensor-flow-shuffle-batch-blocks-at-end-of-epoch)

Comment: So if `coord.should_stop()` is true, my input queue has emptied. How do I tell my input_producer to fill up the queue again? What is the recommended way of doing this?